# Long Polling with RxSwift

Tags: swift, operators, rx-java, long-polling, rx-swift

I want to make a simple long polling request with RxSwift which may be the similar to RxJava code below:

```
api.loadHotels(searchRequest)
    .repeatWhen(obs -> observable.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .takeUntil(searchResponse -> searchResponse.isCompleted)
    .subscribe(listener::hotelListLoaded);
```

In RxSwift, there is a [repeatWhen](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt/issues/38) operator that takes an ObservableConvertibleType as a parameter, not passing the chained Observable to its closure as an argument, unlike its synonym in RxJava.

What I expected in RxSwift: `api.loadHotels(searchRequest).repeatWhen{result -> ObservableConvertibleType}` so I can write the exact same logic as RxJava code. But I cannot achieve this. Because it is only as `api.loadHotels(searchRequest).repeatWhen(ObservableConvertibleType)` The exact same thing applies for RxSwift's `takeUntil` operator.

However I also tried:
[repeatWhen operator in RxSwift](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt/issues/38) and
[repeatWhen substituter in RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/396)

So my question is: how can I achieve the same logic in RxSwift as the given RxJava code? Am I getting the workflow of current `repeatWhen` and `takeUntil` operators of RxSwift wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?:

```
let hotelRequest = api.loadHotels(searchRequest)

hotelRequest.repeatWhen {
    return hotelRequest.flatMapLatest { result in
        // now you have your chance to use `result -> ObservableConvertibleType`
    }
}
```